# Regular Expression Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to get number with sign from a string.

eg:

```
-675.5+987.5i
+675.5-987.5i
```

output:

```
-675.5

+987.5

+675.5

-987.5
```

Comment: Accept your recent questions.

Answer (score 3):

```
var numbers = "-675-987i".match(/[-+]\d+(\.\d+)?/g);
```

Edited to handle also plus sing and float value.

Comment: var number ="-675.5-987.7i" ---> output=-675.5,-987.7

Comment: It returns an array - just handle it as an array :)

Comment: var number=this.match(/(-|\+)?\d+\.?\d*/g) get the output thanks a lot

Comment: @Tarun if this was what you're after please click  the "V" icon to the left to Accept this answer as correct. If for your own reasons you insist on not doing so it's your choice but people will simply stop helping you in this place.